# Convert dd.mm.yyyy format to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript

How can I convert dd.mm.yyyy format date to yyyy-mm-dd format in JavaScript?

Here is an example:

```
30.01.2010
to 
2010-01-30
```

Meaning convert d.m.Y to Y-m-d. I know how to do this in PHP but I need it in JavaScript.

Comment: Just for the record: the customary format used in the US is actually 01/30/2010 (for the date posted in the question): see http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/M/middle-endian.html

Comment: Indeed, 2010-01-30 isn't US format, but standard global ISO 8601 format, and it's definitely the one you want to use wherever possible to avoid ambiguity between the “Euro” dd/mm/yyyy and “US” mm/dd/yyyy ordering.

Comment: @bobince Do you see the use of the ISO format growing?

Comment: @c0mrade: I assume by "European format" you mean that the least significant part comes first; day month year order. But the separator varies. In Germany it is "." (as in your example) and in France it is "/". In Ireland it can be "-" (as well as the two order forms.) There is a Wikipedia article describing this is great detail for many countries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_by_country

Comment: It's certainly making progress, driven by the slow process of standardisation in a few countries, and public exposure to global communications (eg. web sites) where it is necessary as the only unambiguous format. It'll be a long time before it's accepted as the ‘usual’ format, especially in places like the US — hell, we can't even get those guys off the 'orrible 12 hour clock (or imperial measurements!) — but it'll be understood by a growing proportion of people. [edit: just posting the same link as Peter did!]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) can parse that.  The code is at http://datejs.googlecode.com/files/date.js

EDIT: It is *not* safe to left date.js determine the format string automatically. I made the mistake of not testing with a day <= 12 (duh).  You should use:

```
Date.parseExact('09.01.2010', 'd.M.yyyy').toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

or

```
Date.parseExact('09.01.2010', 'dd.MM.yyyy').toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

depending on whether you want to allow single digit days.

Comment: We use date.js for our app, and it has different localised files to format or parse de date depending on local settings. If you take the US format(mm/dd) and enter the date in European format(dd/mm), date.js will not understand it right. You need to load the correct file if you want it to work properly.

Comment: Mic, thank you for the heads-up.  I retested, and my original code actually works (on all inputs) on en-GB, but not en-US (even though I was using en-US to test).  @c0mrade, make sure you use the above fix.

Comment: Does not work, getting: Uncaught TypeError: Date.parseExact is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:30

Answer (score 22):

You can do this pretty simply. Just split the european date into an array, reverse it, and then join it with dashes.

```
var euro_date = '30.01.2010';
euro_date = euro_date.split('.');
var us_date = euro_date.reverse().join('-');
```

Answer (score 9):

Datejs is a bit bloated if you only need to do this. You can use `split()` and concatenate the results:

```
var eu_date = '30.01.2010';
var parts = eu_date.split('.');
var us_date = parts[2]+'-'+parts[1]+'-'+parts[0];
```

For these kinds of conversions where no date logic is needed, it's usually smartest to just use string manipulation tools.

Comment: Yes, but it might be nice to know whether the European date is valid (depending on where it's coming from).

Answer (score 2):

```
    function stringToDate( value ) {
      var isEuro = value.match( /^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/ )
      var isIso = value.match( /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/ )

      if ( isEuro ) {
        value = value.split('.')
        value = [value[2],value[1],value[0]].join('-') //.reverse() isn't working in IEdge
        isIso = true
      }

      if ( isEuro || isIso ) {
        var date = new Date( value )
      }

      if ( isNaN( date.getTime() ) || !isIso ) {
         return false
      }


      return date
    }

    stringToDate('30.01.2000') //Sun Jan 30 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
    stringToDate('30.1.2000') //Sun Jan 30 2000 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
    stringToDate('2000-01-30') //Sun Jan 30 2000 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
    stringToDate('2000-1-30') //Sun Jan 30 2000 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
// Results below assume UTC timezone - your results may vary

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date));
// expected output: "12/20/2012"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date));
// expected output: "20/12/2012"

// Include a fallback language, in this case Indonesian
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(['ban', 'id']).format(date));
// expected output: "20/12/2012"
```

This information is hosted in the Mozilla Development Network (MDN):
[Intl.DateTimeFormat MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

You can have a date in the form of DateString, for example: "Thu Oct 03 2019".
Having this we can convert it in the format we would like, but first we have to convert this string to an object containing the information of the date:

`let convertedDate = new Date("Thu Oct 03 2019")`

Then we can convert the date in the format that we would like to have it:

`let FinalDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(convertedDate)`

Change "en-GB" to "en-US" if you live in the United States, search for other formats if these are not what you need you can always look for other language codes here:

[Language locale codes](https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php)