# How to convert American date format to European

Tags: javascript, date

from : `5/19/2011`

to : `2011-05-19`

I need it to raise an error when it finds that it cannot be real like `5/40/2011` etc. Are there any libraries that do it well?

Comment: There is no such format as a "European" format as there are many different constituencies and cultures involved.

Comment: so what is the proper name for this: `2011-05-19` date format ?

Comment: Thats called Big-Endian http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/2258351/759452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Datejs an open source date library? Specifically:

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact

```
Date.parseExact("10/15/2004", "M/d/yyyy");  // The Date of 15-Oct-2004
Date.parse("15-Oct-2004", "d-MMM-yyyy");    // The Date of 15-Oct-2004
Date.parse("2004.10.15", "yyyy.MM.dd");     // The Date of 15-Oct-2004
Date.parseExact("10/15/2004", ["M/d/yyyy", "MMMM d, yyyy"]); // The Date of 15-Oct-2004
```

Return Value
{Date} A Date object or null if the string cannot be converted into a Date.

or

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#validateDay

```
Date.validateDay(15, 2007, 1);  // true, 15-Feb-2007
Date.validateDay(31, 2007, 10); // false, throws RangeError exception
```

Return Value
{Boolean} true if within range, otherwise false.

Comment: Can I have some feedback for the -1 please? I realise this is a very very old answer, if someone has something to comment upon please share.

Answer (score 8):

maybe this is not best solution, but you can try the simple way like:

```
var from="5/19/2011";
var temp = from.split("/");
var to = temp[2] + "-" + temp[0] + "-" + temp[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

[**edit**] right, you wanted a check too, so added fn `chkDat`:

```
function zeroPad(n){
  return (parseInt(n,10)<10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}

var usdat = '5/19/2011'.split('/')
    ,eudat = [usdat[2],zeroPad(usdat[0]),zeroPad(usdat[1])];

alert(chkDat(usdat,eudat); //=> true
alert(eudat.join('-'));    //=> '2011-05-19'

function chkDat(orig,eu){
   var eu = new Date(eu.join('/'));
   return   eu.getMonth()+1 === parseInt(orig[0],10)
         && eu.getDate() === parseInt(orig[1],10)
         && eu.getFullYear() === parseInt(orig[2],10)
   ;
}
```

**Note** the date format you're after is called *Calendar date* ([ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/date_and_time_format.htm#who-uses-this-standard)).