# Converting the code below to display the date in european format

Tags: javascript

the IsDateValid function below validates date in an american format.What do i change to convert it to validate the date in a European format. when the validate works a user is able to enter the date by simply entering a + or - sign depending on what they want i.e. a past date, or a future date.

```js
function IsLeapYear(year) {
  //Convert from string to number
  year = year - 0;
  if ((year/4)   != Math.floor(year/4)) return false;
  if ((year/100) != Math.floor(year/100)) return true;
  if ((year/400) != Math.floor(year/400)) return false;
  return true;
 } //function IsLeapYear...
 function countChar(str, daChar) {
  //See how many of 'dachar' are in 'str' and return as daCount
  var daCount=0;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   if (str.charAt(i) == daChar)
    //increment count each time we find daChar in str
    daCount++; 
  }
  return daCount;
 } //function countChar...
 function IsDateValid(dateField, noDateRqrd) {
     //If no date is required and they didn't enter one, then go back
  if (((typeof noDateRqrd != "undefined") && (dateField.value.length == 0))||dateField.value.length == 0)
   return null;
  //We're going to check this date so go on
  var GoodLength = false;
  var msg='';
  var daysOfMonth = new Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
  var daysOfMonthLY = new Array(31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
  //Make sure they have the right number of '/'
  var cCount=countChar(dateField.value,'/');
  //force a date value
  if (dateField.value.length >= 3) {
   //alert('cc: ' + cCount + 'fl: ' + dateField.value.length);
   if ((cCount == 1) && (dateField.value.length >= 3) && (dateField.value.length <= 5)) 
      GoodLength=true;
   else if ((cCount == 2) && (dateField.value.length >= 4) && (dateField.value.length <= 10))
      GoodLength=true;
  }
  //If the length is good, then let's check the contents of the dateField
  if (GoodLength == true) {
   var firstslash=dateField.value.indexOf('/')+1; //must add 1 to get real position
   var lastslash=dateField.value.lastIndexOf('/')+1;
   /****************************
   Note: substr is not included in CFStudio so 'substr' will not be bolded & blue
   *****************************/
   var month=dateField.value.substr(0,firstslash-1);
   if ((!isNaN(month)) && (month < 13)){
    if (firstslash != lastslash) {
     //alert(dateField.value);
     var day=dateField.value.substr(firstslash,lastslash-firstslash-1); //lastslash-firstslash+1
     //We only need to tell it where to cut off the first char 
     var year=dateField.value.substr(lastslash);
     //Access dates can range from 100 to 9999.
     //SQL Server dates can range from 1753 to 9999. 
     //Since this code can run for either db, we'll use the more restrivtive date of 1753. 
     //The length test will catch any date > 9999.
     if (!isNaN(day)&&!isNaN(year)&&(year.length < 5)){
      //If there isn't a year value, then put in the current year
      if (year.length == 0) {
       //There is no year so we only need to get day
       var day=dateField.value.substr(firstslash,lastslash-firstslash-1);
       //Since they didn't enter a year, we'll use the current year 
       var now = new Date();
       year=now.getFullYear();
       dateField.value = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
      } else if ((year.length == 1) || (year.length == 2)) {
       var tmpDate = new Date(dateField.value);
       //Programmer's Note: entered value of "00" would be return as "1900" by getFullYear
       tmpDate_yyyy = tmpDate.getFullYear()-1900; //Get 4 dig date and reindex without centuary           
       //alert('tmpDate_yyyy: ' + tmpDate_yyyy);
       if (tmpDate_yyyy < 100) { //If less than 100, then we're in 20th centuary
        if (tmpDate_yyyy < 60)  //do 00 to 59 as 20xx
         tmpDate.setFullYear(2000 + tmpDate_yyyy); //reset year to 21st centuary  
        else //do 60 to 99 as 19xx
         tmpDate.setFullYear(1900 + tmpDate_yyyy); //reset year to 20th centuary 
        //Have to do it the hard way or we'll also get day, time, etc. which we don't want here
        //getMonth is zero based so it returns a number one less that we want
       }
       dateField.value = tmpDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + tmpDate.getDate() + "/" + tmpDate.getFullYear();
      } else if ((year.length == 4)&&(year > 1752)) {
       dateField.value = day + "/" + Month + "/" + year;
      } else {
       msg= 'The date you entered is not valid: ' + dateField.value + '.';
      }//if
     } else {
      msg= 'The date you entered is not valid: ' + dateField.value + '.';
     } //if
    } else {
     //There is no year so we only need to get day
     var day=dateField.value.substr(firstslash);
     if (!isNaN(day)) {
      //Since they didn't enter a year, we'll use the current year 
      var now = new Date();
      var year=now.getFullYear();
      dateField.value = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
     } else {
      msg= 'The day you entered is not valid: ' + dateField.value + '.';
     } //if
    }
    //alert('m: ' + month + ' d: ' + day + ' y:' + year);
    if ((day==0)||(IsLeapYear(year) && day > daysOfMonthLY[month-1])||(!IsLeapYear(year) && day > daysOfMonth[month-1]))
     msg= 'The date you entered is not valid: ' + dateField.value + '.';
   } else {
    msg='The month you entered is not valid: ' + month + '.';
   }
    } else {
   if (dateField.value.length == 0) {
    msg= 'You must enter enter a valid Date.';   
   } else if ((dateField.value.toLowerCase() == 'today')||(dateField.value.toLowerCase() == 'now')) {
    var now = new Date();
    var day=now.getDate();
    var month=now.getMonth()+1; //Have to add 1 to get correct month
    var year=now.getFullYear();
    dateField.value = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
   } else if ((dateField.value.indexOf('+') == 0)||(dateField.value.indexOf('-') == 0)) {
    //alert('in: ' + dateField.value + ', NaN: ' + isNaN(dateField.value));
    if (!isNaN(dateField.value)) {
     var now = new Date();
     var nowMS = now.getTime(); //Get the current time in milliseconds
     //Add the number of milliseconds in a day times the number of days requested
     //Use the Math.floor to make sure we only get whole days in case they add a decimal value
     now.setTime(nowMS + Math.floor((dateField.value * 1000*60*60*24))); 
     var day=now.getDate();
     var month=now.getMonth()+1; //Have to add 1 to get correct month
     var year=now.getFullYear();
     dateField.value = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;    
    } else 
     msg= 'The proper format, +#, or -#, with no spaces in between: e.g., "+6", or "-2". You entered: "' + dateField.value + '".';
   } else
     msg= '146: The date you entered is not valid: "' + dateField.value + '".';
  }
    if(msg.length > 0) {
   if (typeof noDateRqrd == 'undefined') {
      var lastLine="Select 'OK' to re-enter value, or 'Cancel' to enter the current date.\n\n"
   } else {
    var lastLine="Select 'OK' to re-enter value, or 'Cancel' to clear the date.\n\n"
   }
   var conmsg ="\n\n____________________________________________________\n\n" + 
       msg +
          "\n\n____________________________________________________\n\n" +
       "A valid date must contain at least one forward slash '/' as well as a day and a month.\n" +
       "If you leave the year blank, then the current year will be inserted.\n\n" +
       "The allowable date range is from 1/1/1753 to 12/31/9999.\n\n" + 
       lastLine
   if (confirm(conmsg))
    dateField.focus();
   else {
    if (typeof noDateRqrd == 'undefined') {
     //get the current time 
     var Now=new Date();
     dateField.value=Now.getMonth()+1 + "/" + Now.getDate() + "/" + Now.getFullYear();
    } else {
     dateField.value="";
    }
   }
   return false;
  } else
   return true;
 } //function IsDateValid
```

Comment: Have a look at moment.js ? Why invent the wheel again? Also you have a huge amount of code that can be replaced by creating a date object and test that the year==obj.getFullYear(), the month == obj.getMonth()+1 and day == obj.getDate()

Comment: And have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059649/how-to-convert-american-date-format-to-european and many other

Comment: Still struggling with the function