# How to fetch numbers from string date value and format to american date input

Tags: javascript, regex, date, date-fns

I am using `date-fns` which only accept the date value like number.
example:

`new Date(2019, 7, 15)` But I am getting date value from input as:

`07/15/2019` - string. how to convert this string value in to numbers like above mentioned?

especially looking for regex approach. some thing like:

`new Date('07/15/2019' - converted to 2019, 7, 15)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert American date format to European](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059649/how-to-convert-american-date-format-to-european) -

Comment: `new Date` is native javascript Date object. It is not specific to `date-fns` which expects native Date object as input

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this approach, works fine for me:

```
var date = "14/07/2019".replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1").replace(/0/g, '').split('/').join(',');
console.log( date );
```