# How to get the day of week from a string containing date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string like this:

```
'dd-mm-yyyy'
```

for example:

```
'06-03-2015'
```

Now I need to get which day of the week was / is / will be on that specific day. So from the example string the output would be 5 (Friday is the fifth day of week).

I know about the getDay() method, but the string doesn't have to represent the current date.

Comment: `var date = new Date('2015-03-06'); date.getDay()` Not sure why you think the current date has anything to do with it. **Edit** Realised a bit late that the date format was a weird one. But IMO that's an other issue.

Comment: @Biffen it parses the date in the *mm-dd-yyyy* format. OP wants *dd-mm-yyyy*

Comment: Be warned that what @Biffen suggests will set the date to Jun 3rd, not March 6th, which may or may not be what you expect. But that's basically the way to do what you need.

Comment: Heres a solution to that problem though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258293/convert-european-time-format-to-usa

Comment: OK, new attempt: `var date = new Date('06-03-2015'.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/, "$3-$2-$1")); date.getDay()` → `5`