# Javascript: check date in future in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to check the users input field to see if it is in the future and if it is in dd/mm/yyyy format but I have no idea why the format part of my code doesn't fire at all! In fact nothing seems to be working on Jsfiddle but at least my "check date in the future" function works locally.

I don't know the correct way of going about this.

to explain this, I've created this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ce68s2mm/)

And this is my full javascript code. I need to stay with pure javascript by the way:

```
function checkdate(){
    //var sendDate = document.getElementById('send_year').value + '/' + document.getElementById('send_month').value + '/' + document.getElementById('send_day').value;
    var sendDate = document.getElementById('returning_date').value;






    sendDate = new Date(Date.parse(sendDate.replace(/-/g,' ')))
    today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0)
    if (sendDate < today) {
        //alert('The  date can\'t be in the past. Please pick another date.');

        document.getElementById('error8').innerHTML = 'The  date can\'t be in the past. Please pick another date.';
        return false;
    }
    else
{
   document.getElementById('error8').innerHTML = '';
}


if(sendDate.match(/^[0-9]{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/))
{
  alert('works out');
}

}
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your fiddle, you are not defining the HTML elements that your code is using, also you have to set the fiddle to put the code in the head, right now it's running in an onload handler, so it's creating a private checkDate function

Comment: @JuanMendes, I'm using checkdate() on the HTML element (form input).

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are trying to run sendDate.match, but sendDate has been converted into a Date object so it does not have a match method.

You should run your regular expression before you convert it to a Date, in validation, you typically check that the input conforms to a format before you run further validation like range validation.

Answer (score 1):

Date strings should always be manually parsed, you should never allow the Date constructor or Date.parse to parse strings (the Date constructor parses strings in exactly the same way Date.parse does).

To parse and validate a date string is fairly straight forward, just parse the string and see if you get a valid date:

```js
/* Parse a string in d/m/y format. Separator can be any non–digit
** Avoid conversion of two digit dates to 20th century
** Returns an invalid Date if string is not a valid date (per ECMA-262)
**
** @param {string} s - Date string to parse
** @returns {Date}
*/
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  d.setFullYear(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Test valid date
document.write(parseDMY('23/01/2016'));
// Test invalid date
document.write('<br>' + parseDMY('35/12/2016'));
```

Note that this will accept a date like 1/5/16 and treat is as 1 May, 0016. If you want to guarantee that the day and month values have two digits and the year for, then add:

```
/^\d\d\D\d\d\D\d{4}$/.test(s)
```

to the validation test at the end. However, I don't like forcing 2 digits for day and month as people don't usually write dates as "01/08/2016", they use "1/8/2016".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the function needs to be wrapped in `<head>` (hit the cog in the js tab), otherwise the function can't be found.

But your main problem is that you are using European style of date formatting, so you'll get a "Invalid Date" exception when creating the date. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258293/convert-european-time-format-to-usa) on how to convert it to USA-style and make it available for the `Date` object (check [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for all possible uses)

Comment: If you are simply referencing another answer, you should mark this question as a duplicate of that or post this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```js
Date.prototype.fromString = function(str) {
  var m = str.match(/([0-9]{2})(-|\/)([0-9]{2})(-|\/)([0-9]{4})/);
  if (m == null) {
    return null;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(m[i]) === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    };
  };
  var year = parseInt(m[5]);
  var month = parseInt(m[1]) - 1;
  var day = parseInt(m[3]);
  if (month == 0 || day == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return new Date(year, month, day);
}




function checkdate(e, obj, errMsgSel){
  var sendDate =obj.value;

  sendDate = (new Date()).fromString(sendDate);
  if (sendDate == null) {
    if (e.type == 'blur') {
      obj.value = '';
    }
    return;
  }
  today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0)
  if (sendDate < today) {
    //alert('The  date can\'t be in the past. Please pick another date.');

    document.getElementById(errMsgSel).innerHTML = 'The  date can\'t be in the past. Please pick another date.';
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById(errMsgSel).innerHTML = '';
  }
}        $(function () {
});
```

```html
<input onblur="checkdate(event, this, 'error8');" onKeyUp="checkdate(event, this, 'error8');" type='text' name="text1" placeholder='dd/mm/yyyy' id='returning_date'>
<span id='error8' style='color:red;'>format</span> <br><Br>
```

Comment: what is it suppose to do? and yes I have tried the snippets as well and nothing works!!

Comment: sorry, What message? I don't see any message anywhere. and I tried 12/30/2015 and it should say the format is wrong and also "The  date can\'t be in the past. Please pick another date."

Comment: I'm sorry, I just updated my snippet. The months are in the range 0 - 11, this is my mistake. Try now with 12/30/2015  annd let me know.

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't do what i need it to do which is alerting or showing some sort of a message if the format is anything other than dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried to do my best to help you. Sorry again